# Find the k-th valid brackets sequence

Tags: algorithm, brackets

I'm trying to solve pretty complex problem with brackets sequences.

Let's define a valid brackets sequence if:

- The string is empty
- The string has the form (B) where B is valid bracket sequence.
- The string has the form LR where both L and R are valid bracket sequences.

Let's say now that we have two integers N and K. We define a bracket sequence of type N which has exactly N '(', open brackets and exactly N ')', closed brackets. Our task is to find the Kth bracket sequences if the bracket sequences are ordered in lexicographic order.

**Constraints**

N <= 100

K <= 10^18

**Example**

Let's say N = 3, we have 5 valid bracket expressions.

1. ((()))
2. (()())
3. (())()
4. ()(())
5. ()()()

Our task is to return the Kth sequence from this order.

**What I think for the solution**

I think that we should first do some calculations with dynamic programming and then return the Kth permutation. However, I'm stuck with the dynamic programming calculations. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there some limits?

Comment: Yes, I will update the post now.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188634/n-textth-in-lexicographical-order-term-of-balanced-brackets-string